# formula to calculate dew point from temperature and humidity

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Can anyone help me to calculate dew point from the temperature in both (°C or °F) with the relative humidity. I have searched lot on Google but not found any appropriate formula to calculate this. I am using the below formula but it gives wrong values in Fahrenheit unit.

```
float Temp = [value floatValue];
float Humi = [[data humidity] floatValue];
float Td = Temp - ((100 - Humi)/3.6);
return Td;
```

I have the temperature (°C or °F) and humidity and need help in formula to calculate dew point in objective C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly

```
 
-(float) findDewPointWithHumidity:(float) humi forTemperature:(float) temperature isCelsius: (BOOL) isCelsius isReturnTypeCelcius: (BOOL) isReturnTypeCelcius
{
    float temp;

    if(isCelsius){
        temp = temperature;
    } else {
        temp = (temperature - 32) / 1.8;
    }

    float ans =  (temp - (14.55 + 0.114 * temp) * (1 - (0.01 * humi)) - pow(((2.5 + 0.007 * temp) * (1 - (0.01 * humi))),3) - (15.9 + 0.117 * temp) * pow((1 - (0.01 * humi)), 14));

    if(isReturnTypeCelcius){
        return ans;
    }

    float value = ans*(9.0/5.0);
    return value+32.0;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do the job. Below Code only take Celsius and Fahrenheit in account. To use other units of temperature, modify code accordingly;

```
-(float) findDewPointWithHumidity:(float) humidity forTemperature:(float) temperature isCelsius: (BOOL) isCelsius isReturnTypeCelcius: (BOOL) isReturnTypeCelcius
{
    float temp;

    if(isCelsius){
        temp = temperature;
    } else {
        temp = (temperature - 32) / 1.8;
    }

    float humi = 34;
    float ans =  (temp - (14.55 + 0.114 * temp) * (1 - (0.01 * humi)) - pow(((2.5 + 0.007 * temp) * (1 - (0.01 * humi))),3) - (15.9 + 0.117 * temp) * pow((1 - (0.01 * humi)), 14));

    if(isReturnTypeCelsius){
        return ans;           // returns dew Point in Celsius
    } 

    return (temperature - 32) / 1.8;   // returns dew Point in Fahrenheit
}
```

Comment: Its ok in °C but I want to calculate with Fahrenheit too.

Comment: thnx but it will return same result because we converted the °F in °C but I want different result in both case like http://www.dpcalc.org/

Comment: I have edited again. Units of dew point is similar to temperature. You will have to use same formula for conversion.

Comment: thanks lot I have edited this little bit in my answer and it works perfectly..:)